# Oracle 11 Index only for part of the data

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, oracle11g

I'm using a table a table called T and have a column called C_I (Index) and C_D (Data).

Now I would like to only have the row in the index if C_D = null.

`CREATE INDEX T_INDEX ON T(C_I) STORAGE(BUFFER_POOL KEEP);`

How do I get some `WHERE C_D IS NULL` clause into this create statement?

Comment: You can't index rows, so I assume you mean column? As far as I know you can't index for only specific values. You have to index the whole column, which is good. It's not worth trying to change that even if you could. What happens if you want to use the index for something else tomorrow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me first make sure I understand the question correctly:

- You want to speed-up `SELECT .. WHERE C_D IS NULL` but you do **not** want to speed-up any of the queries that search for a non-NULL C_D.
- You also want to make sure no "unnecessary" non-NULL values are in the index, to save space.

If that understanding is correct, then what you need is a **functional** index. I'e. an index on a function on a field, not a field itself...

```
CREATE INDEX T_IE1 ON T (CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) COMPRESS
```

...which you would then query as...

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
```

...which is equivalent to...

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_D IS NULL
```

...but faster since it uses the index:

[image]

This saves space because single-column indexes do not store NULLs. Also, use `COMPRESS` since index will ever only contain one key so there is no need to waste space on repeating the same key over and over again in the index structure.

NOTE: Under Oracle 11, you could also create a [function-based virtual column](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=510) (based on the `CASE` expression above), then index and query on that column directly, to save some repetitive typing.

**--- EDIT ---**

If you are also interested in querying on C_I together with `C_D IS NULL`, you could...

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_IE2 ON T (C_I, CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

...and query it with (for example)...

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_I > 'some value' AND (CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
```

...which is equivalent of...

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_I > 'some value' AND C_D IS NULL
```

...but faster, since it uses the index `T_IE2`.

This is in fact the only index that you need on your table (it "covers" the primary key, so you no longer need a separate index just on C_I). Which also means a same ROWIDs is never stored in more than one index, which saves space.

NOTE: `COMPRESS` no longer makes sense for index `T_IE2`.

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

If you care about simplicity more than space, you can just create a composite index on {C_I, C_D}. Oracle stores NULL values in composite index as long as there is at least one non-NULL value in the same tuple:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_IE3 ON T (C_I, C_D)
```

This uses the index:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_I > 1 AND C_D IS NULL
```

As in previous EDIT, this is the only index that you need on your table.

Comment: Thanks +1, nearly did the trick: CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN C_I ELSE NULL END, and no compression. I'm still interested in the values of C_I.

Comment: @FranzKafka *How* interested are you in the values of C_I? I.e. will you mostly query them stand-alone or will you mostly query them in combination with C_D? In the former case, just let the Oracle optimize usage of 2 separate indexes (on C_I and C_D) and save some space on the C_D index. In the latter case, a_horse_with_no_name's solution looks good but the C_D index will be almost as large as C_I index which may defeat to whole point of your question (to avoid that, you might want to look at replacing C_I index with a composite index on {C_I, `CASE WHEN C_D...`}).

Comment: Do I have to use this special select clause? Or can I do SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_D IS NULL AND C_I = 'someValue'? Because the index isn't used :-(

Comment: @FranzKafka Your `WHERE` expression has to match the index expression. I checked my solution and it definitely uses the index. You should be able to apply similar approach with a_horse_with_no_name's solution as well.

Comment: I query C_I as a range query. WHERE C_I < 'someNumber' and C_D is null. I only query C_I in combination with C_D being NULL.

Comment: Yeah your right, with the specical syntax it works. But I would like to keep the app free of ORACLE syntax. Can you somehow tell the index to react on a normal SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_D IS NULL AND C_I < 'someNumber'

Comment: My experience is that Oracle can use an index on `xxx` for a query like `WHERE xxx IS NULL` without any "tricks"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried this on my `CASE` an it **didn't** use the index. Didn't try on yours, but I would assume it would behave the same.

Comment: @FranzKafka You should be able to "hide" the `CASE` behind a function-based virtual column, as mentioned in my answer. BTW, see my edit for a "combined" query in C_I and C_D. Note that you should be able to achieve similar effect with a_horse_with_no_name's approach by carefully crafting your `WHERE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 CREATE INDEX T_INDEX ON T ( CASE WHEN CD IS NULL THEN C_I ELSE NULL END);
```

This works because Oracle will not put the null values returned by the CASE statement into the index.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't want to use the index when I query and goes for a full table scan: SELECT * FROM T WHERE C_I = '2011-10-01 00:00:00' AND C_D = NULL. Does oracle know how to use the index at all?

Comment: For such a query I'd try an index on `C_I, C_D` (and don't worry about the size)

Comment: yeah, C_S IS NULL. The size is quite a issue if its only 1 in 10 mio. There must be some cleverer approach to this.

Answer (score 2):

Let me "repackage" my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696467/oracle-11-index-only-for-part-of-the-data/7697119#7697119).

Create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T ...;
CREATE INDEX T_PK_IDX ON T (C_I, CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END);
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT T_PK PRIMARY KEY (C_I) USING INDEX T_PK_IDX;
```

And query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE
    C_I > 'some value'
    AND (CASE WHEN C_D IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 1
```

Query plan:

[image]

Comment: The virtual column did the trick for me. Now I can use a normal sql statement and no oracle exclusiv shit :-) Good job.