# Indexing only part of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

Given the following table in an Oracle database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ID_ORDER NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
    VL_TOTAL NUMBER(19,4) NOT NULL,
    DT_SUBMIT DATE,
    ID_DISCRIMINATOR NUMBER(19) NOT NULL

    --- many many many many other columns
);
```

That is a table of all orders (`DT_SUBMIT` will be NULL until the order is submitted).
The `ID_DISCRIMINATOR` contents is not really relevant (it suffices to know that it is not unique; there are really a small number of discriminators available).

I want to optimize the following query:

```sql
SELECT ID_DISCRIMINATOR, SUM(VL_TOTAL)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE DT_SUBMIT IS NOT NULL
      AND DT_SUBMIT > :some_parameter:
GROUP BY ID_DISCRIMINATOR
```

(OK, I know that `DT_SUBMIT >`  already implies that `DT_SUBMIT IS NOT NULL`; it is just that I want to show it explicitly here)

To optimize this query it I created an index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX BY_SUBMISSION_DATE ON ORDERS (DT_SUBMIT, ID_DISCRIMINATOR, VL_TOTAL)
```

What a improvement (for that query)!!!

But I'm thinking I could do better. The `BY_SUBMISSION_DATE` index doesn't need to include the not yet submitted orders, saving both in index space and table insertion/update/delete time (and also in "index" fragmentation, if this is ever a problem for Oracle databases).

**How can I create that index for only part of the table (`DT_SUBMIT IS NOT NULL`)?**

(I think my question is the opposite of [Oracle 11 Index only for part of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696467/oracle-11-index-only-for-part-of-the-data), because there the OP asks to optimize `SELECT ... WHERE key IS NULL`).

**EDIT**

So far I've learned that Oracle indexes are already partial indexes, albeit not with an arbitrary predicate, but a `IS NOT NULL` one (how lucky I am: that's the predicate I need).

But only if all parts of the indexing key are `NOT NULL`.

So, if my index were instead:

```sql
CREATE INDEX BY_SUBMISSION_DATE ON ORDERS (DT_SUBMIT)
```

...then everything would be fine: that index would be partial already and non-submitted orders would be left out of the index, with the afore mentioned gains.

But... that comes at the cost of query time improvements. Although still better than the "without any index" version, it performs worse than the "composite key index" version.

Is it possible to have the better of both versions?

Comment: I think you are trying to over optimize.  You may find something useful in FUNCTION BASED INDEXES however.

Comment: If all three columns values are `NULL`, Oracle will not add them to the index, otherwise it will.  Oracle does not support partial indexing, unless you are using certain types of partitioned tables.  Your current design may be as good as it gets (for now).

Comment: What fraction of the table is unsubmitted orders?  If unsubmitted orders are, say, 50% of the table, excluding those rows from the index entirely at least produces some plausible benefit.  I'd guess, though, that unsubmitted orders are a very small fraction of the rows in the table.  Making an index 5% smaller is going to have no impact on query performance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, all three columns are never NULL (`ID_DISCRIMINATOR` and `VL_TOTAL` are both `NOT NULL`). I'll have a look on partitioned tables.

Comment: @JustinCave I was actually trying to optimize data modification (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) on the table. But I understand your point: I should put energy optimizing things that will make a difference. Unfortunately, I don't have access to production database, so I can't say how much of the table could be excluded.